# Can't get Ajax call to work with TypeAhead

Tags: jquery, json, typeahead

Trying to get TypeAhead & Twitter bootstrap to work with an AJAX/Json call... it works without Ajax.

Getting error saying: unable to get property length of undefined or null reference

```
<var id="result-container" class="result-container"></var>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <input id="field" placeholder="Start typing.." class="typeahead" data-items="3" type="text">  
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="addRow">
    <button id="btnAddRow" class="btn">Add Row</button> 
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var typeaheadSettings = {
    source: function (typeahead, query) {

     return $.get('search.json', { query: query }, function (data) {
        return typeahead.process(data);
     });

    // return ['dingbat','alpha','asphalt','beta','bravo','delta','epsilon','gamma','zulu'];




    }
};

$('.typeahead').typeahead(typeaheadSettings); /* init first input */

$('#btnAddRow').click(function(){
    var newRow = $('<div class="row"><input type="text" placeholder="Start typing.." class="typeahead" data-items="3"></div>');
    newRow.insertBefore('#addRow');
    $('.typeahead').trigger('added');

});

$('.typeahead').on('added',function(){
    $('.typeahead').typeahead(typeaheadSettings);
});


</script>
```